# How to control the playback rate of swf flash video in HTML<object>

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to change the playbackRate of the `.swf` video in the website?
Is there a `setplayRate()` JS function or arttributes?

For example, how to change this using JS:

```
<object width="400" height="40"
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/
pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param name="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
<embed src="bookmark.swf" width="400" height="40"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: If you are looking for a setup that changes the number of frames displayed per second then Andrew Sellenrick's post is worthwhile to check. But if it is not, can you please give more details about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a few things you could try, not sure what exactly you are trying to do and what your limitations are.

You can change the framerate in a swf by using

```
stage.frameRate = 24;
```

You can also just playback movieclips at any framerate you want without changing the global framerate by using TweenMax.

```
TweenMax.to(mc, seconds, {frame: this.totalFrames - 1});
```

If you have either of these setup in your code you could call them from the js using ExternalInterface. Good Luck!